# How to detect whether DDS is installed in the Windows system?

Tags: nsis, data-distribution-service

I want to install OpenSplice DDS using nsis script, but i have to know whether the OpenSplice DDS installed or not in the system (Windows).

Based on the register keys how can we check if OpenSplice DDS is installed or not?

Can anybody provide the nsis script to check DDS installation based on registery keys?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us which registry key you want to check...

Comment: When you say "OpenSplice DDS installed", do you mean to say "OpenSplice DDS installed by means of the installer which comes with the commercial edition"?

Comment: @Anders Thank you.yes.you are correct.which Registry key i want to check whether DDS installed or not?? Based on this result only i am going to do further process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard OpenSplice installation does not make any changes to the registry and as such, you can not use checking of the registry key to discover whether or not OpenSplice has been installed. Only if the option to install OpenSplice as a Windows service was checked during installation, information will be inserted into the registry -- just like any Windows service has an entry in the registry. Since it is up to the user to select this option or not, this is not a reliable mechanism to check for either.

A better way might be to check whether the environment variable `%OSPL_HOME%` is set. This variable is typically added to the environment by the OpenSplice installer; it points to its installation directory.

This answer is based on previous experience with the product. I do not have access to any current version, so the installation process might have changed.

Comment: Thank you.I have DDS in this path HKLM\SOFTWARE\PrimsTech\OpenSplice DDS.I have see through Registry editor.but while running following script its not working fine.Its shows no dds message.ReadRegStr $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\PrimsTech" "Version".Do you know??

Comment: I am not sure what happens, but I do see that you have a typo in here: the company is not PrimsTech, but PrismTech.

Comment: oops.sorry here typo error.i have try this as follows:                                                             ReadRegStr $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\PrismTech" "Location"
ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "SOFTWARE\PrismTech\$1"  "Version".but its not working fine.i dont know..why?

Comment: Now the path to your key is missing OpenSplice DDS. It might be better to first try this without any of the variables (like $1), but hard code it first and see if that works. I have no experience with NSIS though.